# php convert string into conditional statements

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have a bi dimensional array of array with homogeneous values.

```
$input = array(
     'x' => 100, 'y' => 101, 'type' => 'yes', value => 10
), array(
     'x' => 110, 'y' => 101, 'type' => 'no', value => 10
), array(
     'x' => 120, 'y' => 102, 'type' => 'yes', value => 99
);
```

I need to find out a way to write a function to filter values passing a "text" filter as input:

```
//extract all values when $tye = yes and $value is greater than 10
custom_filter($input, "type = yes and value > 10");

//extract all values when $x is equal to $y
custom_filter($input, "x = y");

//filter all values for x is pair and y is odd
custom_filter($input, "x % 2 = 0 and y % 2 > 0");
```

---

```
function custom_filter($input_array, $condition) {
     (...)
}
```

Is there a way to "translate" $condition parameter from human readable statement to a php conditional statement?

Comment: This could be done with `eval()` but it would be very difficult to account for all possible commands.

Comment: There is almost no way around marking up your placeholders as PHP variables, because `y`cannot be easily changed to `$y` because that would change also `type` to `t$ype` and `yes` to `$yes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way:

```
$input = [
     ['x' => 100, 'y' => 101, 'type' => 'yes', 'value' => 10],
     ['x' => 110, 'y' => 101, 'type' => 'no', 'value' => 10],
     ['x' => 120, 'y' => 102, 'type' => 'yes', 'value' => 99]
];

function custom_filter($array, $eval) {
    $validate = function ($item) use($eval) {
        extract($item);
        eval('$valid = ' . $eval . ';');

        return $valid;
    };

    return array_filter($array, $validate);
}

//extract all values when $tye = yes and $value is greater than 10
var_dump(custom_filter($input, '$type == "yes" && $value > 10'));

//extract all values when $x is equal to $y
var_dump(custom_filter($input, '$x == $y'));

//filter all values for x is pair and y is odd
var_dump(custom_filter($input, '$x % 2 == 0 && $y % 2 > 0'));
```

Well, you have to write a php code as a condition for extracted values.

Comment: Warning: `eval()` is the devil and you should not let user-submitted data anywhere near it.